# Why can't we use a for loop with increment operator in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Instead of using:

```
for (n = 1; n <= 5; n++) {
  print(n)
}
```

why do we use the following construct in Swift?

```
for n in 1...5 {
    print(n)
}
```

// Output: 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Why do you event want to? You're getting the result without that, right?

Comment: `1...5` is a `Range`. `for n in 1...5` is more equivalent to a for each loop. A range is enumerable, so you can iterate over it. when you use the classic for loop, you are telling the compiler how to manually enumerate the array and it what direction (n++ or n--), it's not really needed in Swift and classic or c-style for loops were deprecated

Comment: “Why can't we use?” and “why didn't we use?” are two different questions.

Comment: If you want to use the increment/decrement operator in Swift, I suggest you look into `stride`

Answer (score 2):

> "I am certainly open to considering dropping the C-style for loop.
>   IMO, it is a rarely used feature of Swift that doesn’t carry its
>   weight. Many of the reasons to remove them align with the rationale
>   for removing -- and ++. "

-- Chris Lattner,

There is a proposal about increment https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md

> These operators increase the burden to learn Swift as a first
>   programming language - or any other case where you don't already know
>   these operators from a different language.
>
> Their expressive advantage is minimal - x++ is not much shorter than x
>   += 1.
>
> Swift already deviates from C in that the =, += and other
>   assignment-like operations returns Void (for a number of reasons).
>   These operators are inconsistent with that model.
>
> Swift has powerful features that eliminate many of the common reasons
>   you'd use ++i in a C-style for loop in other languages, so these are
>   relatively infrequently used in well-written Swift code. These
>   features include the for-in loop, ranges, enumerate, map, etc.
>
> Code that actually uses the result value of these operators is often
>   confusing and subtle to a reader/maintainer of code. They encourage
>   "overly tricky" code which may be cute, but difficult to understand.
>
> While Swift has well defined order of evaluation, any code that
>   depended on it (like foo(++a, a++)) would be undesirable even if it
>   was well-defined.
>
> These operators are applicable to relatively few types: integer and
>   floating point scalars, and iterator-like concepts. They do not apply
>   to complex numbers, matrices, etc.
>
> Finally, these fail the metric of "if we didn't already have these,
>   would we add them to Swift 3?"

And about the loops

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md

> Both for-in and stride provide equivalent behavior using
>   Swift-coherent approaches without being tied to legacy terminology.
>
> There is a distinct expressive disadvantage in using for-loops
>   compared to for-in in succinctness
>
> for-loop implementations do not lend themselves to use with
>   collections and other core Swift types.
>
> The for-loop encourages use of unary incrementors and decrementors,
>   which will be soon removed from the language.
>
> The semi-colon delimited declaration offers a steep learning curve
>   from users arriving from non C-like languages
>
> If the for-loop did not exist, I doubt it would be considered for
>   inclusion in Swift 3.